# Nginx & Docker - how to forward to an internal address?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm searching for a long time for a solution that can solve my problem. I guess the answer is already given but I'm not searching for the right terms.

I'm using NGINX to forward all requests for port 80 and this works well. Because these ones are forwarded to my own public domain. Now I got a service that I do not want to publish on the internet and just have a different port in my network for it so e.g. `192.168.123.1:10000`.

That is what my `nginx.conf` looks like for exemplary service. I got more server blocks for different services. The important part is the `proxy_pass` which is set here to be forwarded to the Docker container `nextcloudpi`. But how can I internally `proxy_pass` something without a real domain?

```
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    location / {
      return 404;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-domain.de cloud.my-domain.de www.my-domain.de;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # Cloud

  server {
    server_name cloud.my-domain.de;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/cloud-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/cloud-error.log;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    client_max_body_size 100G;

    location / {
      proxy_send_timeout 1d;
      proxy_read_timeout 1d;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      #add_header Front-End-Https on;
      proxy_pass https://nextcloudpi;
    }
  }
```

I want to use it for invoice ninja for example. How do I set it in Docker then? I normally use `expose` to let NGINX do everything to do with port 80. But if I want a different internal IP how do I do this? I know how to do it normally in Docker like I tried but that won't work without NGINX:

```
  invoiceninja:
    container_name: invoiceninja
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:latest
    ports:
      - 10000:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /storage/appdata/invoiceninja/public:/var/app/public
      - /storage/appdata/invoiceninja/storage:/var/app/storage
    networks:
      - invoiceninja
    env_file:
      - .secrets/invoiceninja.env
    depends_on:
      - invoiceninja-db
```

Basically, how do I forward port 80 of the invoice ninja Docker container to a different port to access it internally like `192.168.123.1:10000`.

Comment: Assuming 192.168.123.1 is one of the host's IP addresses, that `ports:` declaration does exactly that.  You can `proxy_pass` to a URL with an IP address or a non-default port.

Comment: @DavidMaze so you mean I'll set it as server name 192.168.123.1 or what? I mean that is the big question for me. Like this NGINX only reacts to calls of the domain and knows which server block is responsible. Do you get my problem or better-said question?

Comment: Did I explain it too badly?